# How to send an object from one view to the next

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

Consider the following scenario:

You are in a view with a lot of data (i.e. a view with a `ListBox` full of items). The data has been downloaded from an external data source, and contains a lot of properties that's not exposed in the current view. You'd like to make a detailed view to show this information.

When you have wired up your `ListBoxItem`s to navigate to your new view with an attached "id=" in the navigation URL, you can easily query your data source (i.e. a REST-service) for the data again with the given ID-parameter. But the data is already available on the parent view - so how could you send this data in some way to the next view - skipping another call to your data source and speeding up your application?

Comment: I'm sorry - I'm a bit confused of what you're doing here: you provided answer to your own question almost as soon as you posted the question.

Comment: Thought I'd share my knowledge :-) I spent a lot of hours looking for a good answer to this, and ended up figuring out my own solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are several ways to do this, but this is the easiest way to accomplish it without using any external libraries.

Create a Utility class - `NavigationUtility` (or whatever) - and implement the following structure:

```
public static class NavigationUtility
{
    // The object to send
    private static object passedObject = null;

    // A method to fetch the object
    public static object GetObject() {
        // implementation below
    }

    // Utility method to check if an object was passed
    public static bool HasObject() 
    {
        return passedObject != null;
    }

    // A method to navigate to a page
    public static void Navigate(string url, object obj = null)
    {
        // implementation below
    }
}
```

This is the interface you'll be implementing. It has a private variable that keeps your object safe while transitioning between views, and methods for both navigating and fetching the information sent.

Now there are a few things you need to consider in order to implement this in a correct way.

1. You must only be able to fetch the passed object once - otherwise careless use can make the wrong object show up in the wrong part of the program.
2. In order to use this instead of the `NavigationService.Navigate(Uri)` method for navigating throughout your application, it must also be able to handle situations where no object needs to be sent.

So let's look at the first method in our interface - `GetObject` - and how it's implemented:

```
public static object GetPassedObject() 
{
    var obj = passedObject;
    passedObject = null; 
    return obj;
}
```

As you see, we take care of requirement #1 easily by nulling out the internal passedObject for each time the property is fetched. This would work in the following way (in the receiving view):

```
NavigationUtility.HasObject(); // returns true if an object was sent
var data = NavigationUtility.GetObject() as SomeModel; // fetches the object and casts it
NavigationUtility.HasObject(); // returns false always;
```

Now to the funny bit - implementing the `Navigate`-method:

```
public static void Navigate(string url, object obj = null) 
{
    // Saves the object
    passedObject = obj;

    if( url != null && url.length > 0 )
    {
        // Creates the Uri-object
        Uri uri = new Uri(url, UriKind.Relative);

        // Navigates the user (notice the funky syntax - so that this can be used from any project
        (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(uri);
    }
}
```

And that's it!

Answer (score 0):

with the help creating your data with application object you can easily navigate  your object data to another view when you making call of  REST-service be sure that your data will set to your application object too

you can also use json object and set it to Any global object